# How do I write fragmented xml file without root element?

Tags: c#, xml

I got fragmented xml file (document without root element/node):

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no" ?>
<WndPos name="Login" l="703" r="1264" t="323" b="909" />
<WndPos name="Main" l="703" r="768" t="323" b="609" />
<LayerManager />
<ViewLayers name="Roof" roof="1">
    <Layer level="1" visible="1" />
</ViewLayers>
<DirProfiles>
    <ProfileInfo ProfileName="Control" DatabasePath="D:\Database\Control" />
</DirProfiles>
<DirHistory>
     <ProfileInfo Use="Database" Path="D:\Database\Control" />
</DirHistory>
```

I am reading this file using the following:

```
string xmlPath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERPROFILE") + "\\my.xml";

XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
settings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment;

XDocument doc = new XDocument(new XElement("root"));
XElement root = doc.Descendants().First();

using (StreamReader fs = new StreamReader(xmlPath))
using (XmlReader xr = XmlReader.Create(fs, settings))
{
    while(xr.Read())
    {
        if (xr.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
        {
            root.Add(XElement.Load(xr.ReadSubtree())); 
        }
     }
}
```

Later on I change `<DirProfiles>...</DirProfiles>` section and getting the following data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no" ?>
<WndPos name="Login" l="703" r="1264" t="323" b="909" />
<WndPos name="Main" l="703" r="768" t="323" b="609" />
<LayerManager />
<ViewLayers name="Roof" roof="1">
    <Layer level="1" visible="1" />
</ViewLayers>
<DirProfiles>
    <ProfileInfo ProfileName="Control1" DatabasePath="D:\Database\Control1" />
    <ProfileInfo ProfileName="Control2" DatabasePath="D:\Database\Control2" />
    <ProfileInfo ProfileName="Control3" DatabasePath="D:\Database\Control3" />
    <ProfileInfo ProfileName="Control4" DatabasePath="D:\Database\Control4" />
    <ProfileInfo ProfileName="Control5" DatabasePath="D:\Database\Control5" />
</DirProfiles>
<DirHistory>
     <ProfileInfo Use="Database" Path="D:\Database\Control" />
</DirHistory>
```

This result xml fragment I have to write to the file which should be fragmented xml file (without root element).
I tried to do the following:

```
doc.Save();
```

But it saves with root element and application can't work with this xml.

Comment: Most XML tools and applications only work on well-formed XML documents (as distinct from "fragments", properly "external general parsed entities"). By trying to process and create fragments, you are therefore cutting yourself off from the XML mainstream and greatly limiting your repertoire of tools. Are you sure this is wise?

Comment: So do the same thing in reverse: iterate through the elements and write them separately. Obviously what you've got here is *not* an XML document, so you can't save it as one. ("Fragmented XML" is not some sort of variation on the standard; the result of this is not proper XML at all. It's cute that it still has an XML declaration at the top, though.)

Comment: Easiest way not to not write the ident (first line) of xml is not to read the first line.  So in you streamreader before creating the XmlReader add the line : fs.ReadLine();

Comment: @MichaelKay I am a tester who is writing some test automation and have to work with files which is part of AUT (Application under test), I must work with this file as a given. I can update section, but I can't change whole file. Thanks.

Comment: @jdweng I tried your suggestion, but it didn't remove `<root>` from the doc. Thanks.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Actually this object is some sort of variation on the standard: it's called an External General Parsed Entity. Most XML parsers won't allow you to read an EGPE except by incorporating it (using an entity reference) into a well-formed document entity. You can read it in XPath 3.1 using the parse-xml-fragment() function, and you can also serialize it using the XSLT 3.0 serializer. But I hesitate to put that as an answer because the OP is working in the world of C# with its very antiquated XML support.